# Can't connect my Google Cloud SQL to my local PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, cloud

I am having a problem connecting google cloud sql to my local phpmyadmin.

Here's what I did:

1. set up a new user
2. put my public ip address in the Authorized networks
3. paste the following code below on my phpmyadmin config.inc.php

.

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Google Cloud SQL';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '(my google cloud sql ip)';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

I tested and put `0.0.0.0/0` on my Authorized networks for the server to accept any incoming IP, just to test it out on my localhost and **yes It works**.

It seems like my public IP address in not being Authorized? Even though I put my public IP address in there?

Side note: I just googled my public IP address

Let me know your thoughts.

Thank you so much

Comment: what is the phmyadmin error? Have you tried `mysql -h {IP}` from the same host?

Comment: Putting a SQL server on the public IP address is asking for trouble.